# Insert/Add/Append option in StringUtils in Java

Tags: java, string

Is it possble to convert a string in a/b format to double in Java?
Ex: str = "4/5";
Can I parse this and get float/double value?
I used parseDouble, but did not work and it expects something like "34.33" as input string.

Comment: What you want is to evaluate the math expression and then parse the result to a double. There are libraries for evaluating a math expression in a string format, or you can write your own method for it.

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your expression is always of the type "a/b" you can try something like:

```
String str = "4/5";
String parts[] = str.split("/");
double res = Double.parseDouble(parts[0])/Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
```

Otherwise, use an expression evaluation tool as suggested in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
 String s = "35/6";
 s = s.replace('/', '.');
 double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to evaluate `4/5` and save its double value. You are proposing to use `/` as decimal separator token. I don't think that is right. Your code will result in `d = 35.6` whereas it should be `d = 5.83`

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo Maybe you right

Answer (score -1):

In javascript, you can use function "eval" to do it.But in Java,there is no function like that.So you use ScriptEngine to do it in java.

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine se = manager.getEngineByName("js");
String str = "4/5";
Double result =(Double) se.eval(str);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: why use Javascript for answer on this question ?